# Deploying node.js, gulp, bower app on Cloud Foundry application start issue

Tags: node.js, gulp, cloud-foundry, hygieia

I am deploying node js application consist of bower, gulp etc.
I am able to deploy it and build it successfully at Cloud Foundry but appilcation is not starting. my issue is may be the gulp file is having code with browser sync 
is

```
 browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: dist,
            startPath: '/',
            middleware: [proxyMiddleware]
        }
    });
```

I am not sure what is missing, in fact I am not getting any error but app is not running on cf . by using `cfenv` I am able to give port in browser syc but how I provide 'host' because by default it is working on localhost ?

logs are:

```
2016-11-19T18:23:09.45+0530 [CELL/0]     OUT Creating container
2016-11-19T18:23:10.49+0530 [CELL/0]     OUT Successfully created container
2016-11-19T18:23:11.50+0530 [CELL/0]     OUT Starting health monitoring of container
2016-11-19T18:23:11.94+0530 [APP/0]      OUT > NodejsStarterApp@0.0.1 start /home/vcap/app
2016-11-19T18:23:11.94+0530 [APP/0]      OUT > node app.js
2016-11-19T18:23:12.02+0530 [HEALTH/0]   OUT healthcheck failed
2016-11-19T18:23:12.03+0530 [HEALTH/0]   OUT Exit status 1
2016-11-19T18:23:12.13+0530 [APP/0]      OUT port8080
2016-11-19T18:23:12.13+0530 [APP/0]      OUT bind0.0.0.0
2016-11-19T18:23:12.13+0530 [APP/0]      OUT server starting on https://myapp.u1.app.cloud.myorg.net
2016-11-19T18:23:12.56+0530 [HEALTH/0]   OUT healthcheck failed
2016-11-19T18:23:12.56+0530 [HEALTH/0]   OUT Exit status 1
2016-11-19T18:23:13.09+0530 [HEALTH/0]   OUT healthcheck failed
2016-11-19T18:23:13.09+0530 [HEALTH/0]   OUT Exit status 1
2016-11-19T18:23:13.62+0530 [HEALTH/0]   OUT healthcheck failed
```

any suggestion I welcome..

Comment: CF binds localhost ports by default, that's not the problem. Could you give a [mcve] that shows the manifest, logs from CF, etc.? Also note that you say BlueMix in the title but have tagged PCF; these are two different CF distributions, please clarify which you're using.

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe, I have provide cf only now.. at cloud foundary it starts to listen at localhost:3000 is it fine?.. atually there is no error but cloud foundary 0 of 1 started,, 1 starting logs comes .. and in the end it failes

Comment: What does *"fails"* mean? What errors do you get? Have you tried configuring some logging to stdout in your application so you can `cf logs myapp` and see what's happening? Are you using the CF-provided `PORT` environment variable?

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request, from browser I get this.. I am just redeploying it.. will tails logs and put here @jonrsharpe

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I have put the logs in question.. pls guide on this

Comment: And is that the port that CF is providing? It will listen on the one it injects as `PORT`, if that's not where your app responds you'll fail health checking.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how to inject as PORT ?  i think it uses default port .. not sure on how to inject, 8080 is the middleware that browser sync is using.. for consuming other apis.. I am suppose to run UI at default port and that is 3000

Comment: No. you don't have to inject the port, **CF injects the port**, you have to *configure your app to use it*. You don't actually show where you do that; if you don't do it, *that's the problem*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe as I am redeploying it.  var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv(); and then using  port: appEnv. port in above browserSync function? is there any other way to use cf port I mean getting CF provided port in gulp file ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue deploying as well. I fixed it by putting `-u process` in my cf push command.

Example:

`cf push APP-NAME -b nodejs_buildpack -p . -u process` and it fixed the problem.

`-u` specifies to CF what level of health check to perform.